# Play audio when uicollectionviewcell is clicked in iOS

Tags: ios, collectionview

I want to play mp3 file file when user select a collection view custom cell. but it is not playing . here is the code i have written for this purpose 
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

```
    NSLog(@"cell selected ");
    AVAudioPlayer * audioPlayer;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bismillah" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *audioUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    audioPlayer=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioUrl error:nil];
    //audioPlayer.delegate=self;
    [audioPlayer play];
   // cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

once try like this, and once check is it present in `bundle Resources` or not.

```
NSString *audio=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Ranz des Vaches" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:audio];
avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
avPlayer.delegate = self;
[avPlayer prepareToPlay];
[avPlayer play];
```

Comment: Still not working...can You please list down the steps needed to play audio when collection view cell is selected.

Comment: have you checked in bundle Resources files?

Comment: kindly answer my question ...i have tried may ways but still audio is not playing. Is it possible to play the audio in didSelectItemAtIndexPath delegate function of Collection view cell?

Answer (score 0):

[Check this checkbox.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPAP0.png) Also try to store your player as a class property. It can dealloc when declared as function property.